# Inconsistent Encryption / Decryption Results

Tags: php, mcrypt

I'm having totally confounding encryption/decryption results. I have two different strings that I need to encode and later decode, the encrypted string being stored in a MySQL database in between. The first of these strings comes out just fine. However, the second one always returns from decryption with the value FALSE. I've stripped out all of the non-essential factors, and am directly passing a plaintext value of "test" to both encryption routines. Again, the first one returns correctly (as "test") the second one returns as "false").

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm using the same password and the same salt in both files. How is it possible that one will work but the second won't???

One clue: if I put this code into a single php file and bypass the database, it all works just fine. Not sure what to make of this, but it's interesting at least.

Here is the code. The encryption/decryption routine comes from a user post on the php site for mcrypt. Can anyone see it? It's probably something stupid.

setValues.php

```
$encrypted_email_pw = encrypt("test", $password);
$encrypted_default_pw = encrypt("test", $password);

$sql = "UPDATE Settings 
        SET email_password='$encrypted_email_pw', 
            default_pw='$encrypted_default_pw'
        WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

getValues.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Settings";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //there is only one row in this table

$decrypted_email_pw = decrypt($row['email_password'], $password);
$decrypted_default_pw = decrypt($row['default_pw'], $password);

echo $decrypted_email_pw . " | " . $decrypted_default_pw;
//output:  test | false
die();
```

crypto.php

```
<?php

    function encrypt($decrypted, $password, $salt='6rVDB?zKe6batB+k') { 

        // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
        $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);

        // Build $iv and $iv_base64.  
        // We use a block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode.  
        // (Note: ECB mode is inadequate as IV is not used.)
        srand(); $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
        if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) return false;

        // Encrypt $decrypted and an MD5 of $decrypted using $key.  
        // MD5 is fine to use here because it's just to verify successful decryption.
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

        // We're done!
        return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
    } 

    function decrypt($encrypted, $password, $salt='6rVDB?zKe6batB+k') {

        // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
        $key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);

        // Retrieve $iv which is the first 22 characters plus ==, base64_decoded.
        $iv = base64_decode(substr($encrypted, 0, 22) . '==');

        // Remove $iv from $encrypted.
        $encrypted = substr($encrypted, 22);

        // Decrypt the data.  
        // rtrim won't corrupt the data because the last 32 characters are the md5 hash; 
        // thus any \0 character has to be padding.
        $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0\4");

        // Retrieve $hash which is the last 32 characters of $decrypted.
        $hash = substr($decrypted, -32);

        // Remove the last 32 characters from $decrypted.
        $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -32);

        // Integrity check.  If this fails, either the data is corrupted, or the password/salt was incorrect.
        if (md5($decrypted) != $hash) return false;

        return $decrypted;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do not use a fixed salt.

Comment: Are you saying that this explains the inconsistent results?

Comment: First try to skip the database step entirely, and instead try to hand the data from encryption to decryption in the script itself without passing to SQL or anywhere else. It seems trivial, but first you need to know if the database is effecting the result or if there is something wrong with the handling of the encryption library itself.

Comment: @usr55410: No; it does not.

Comment: I just edited my post to note that I had tried this. It works fine without the db. I've thoroughly tested the storage and retrieval from the db, and I'm getting the results that I would expect. Can't figure out why the db has any role in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the two columns in the Settings table? Do they have the same data types?
And are you sure the encrypt() and decrypt() methods work correctly?

After you get this working, you should consider using a random generated salt for each password and store the salt in the table together with the password.

Comment: That was it. One of my columns was varchar(100) and the other was varchar(50). Thanks!

Comment: This is a very interesting result - and one I did not expect. Giving both the question and the answer an upvote!